# How to check duplicate email from database for subscription email get all email from database and check if duplicate or not then post that email

Tags: css, reactjs, asp.net, user-interface

I am checking the the condition but not shown any result I am try to get all email from database and check it is an already posted or not and show toast message and post that email

```
const onSubmit = async (data,e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let isDuplicate = false;
      emailList.forEach((val) => {
        console.log(val.Email);
        console.log(data.Email);
        if (val.Email === data.Email) {
              isDuplicate = true;
          }
    })
    if (!isDuplicate) {
     axios
      .post("https://localhost:44312/api/ClientSub/AddCSubscriber", data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
       
        toast.success("Successfully! Subscribed to the news letter");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
      reset();
    }
    else{
      
      toast.success("You are already Subscribed");
    }
  
}
useEffect(()=>{
  getAllSubscribers();
},[])
```

Comment: There is so much info missing here. Where do `data.Email` and `emailList` come from. Are there errors in the console, is the `AddCSubscriber` endpoint working correctly.

Comment: const [emailList,setEmailList] = useState([]);  email list variable and getAllSubscribers are getting all email from server

Comment: following is the getAllSubscribers function const getAllSubscribers = async() => {
    await axios.get('https://localhost:44312/api/ClientSub/GetAllCSubscriber')
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res.data.data)
      setEmailList(res.data.data)
    })

  }